# Looking up a Pandas object for methods and properties

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to Pandas and i don't know a lot about its functionality and what it can do. But it will be helpful if there was some kind of lookup methods to check what methods exist from a result of an operation.

An example would be in the chaining example below, if i wanted to lookup the properties of "australianMammals" dataframe. i'm not sure exactly how to go about it except googling examples.

I'll appreciate if anyone could share their thinking process behind finding and selecting the right methods/properties at different stages

```
australianMammals = {
    'kangaroo': {
        'Subclass': 'marsupial', 
        'Species Origin':'native'
    },
    'flying fox': {
        'Subclass': 'placental', 
        'Species Origin': 'native'
    },
    'black rat': {
        'Subclass': 'placental', 
        'Species Origin': 'invasive'
    },
    'platypus': {
        'Subclass': 'monotreme', 
        'Species Origin': 'native'
    },
    'wallaby': {
        'Subclass': 'marsupial',
        'Species Origin': 'native'
    },
    'palm squirrel': {
        'Subclass':'placental', 
        'Origin':'invasive'
    },
    'anteater': {
        'Subclass': 'monotreme',
        'Origin': 'native'
    },
    'koala': {
        'Subclass': 'marsupial',
        'Origin':'native'
    }
}
ozzieMammalsDF=pd.DataFrame(australianMammals)
aussieMammalsDF=ozzieMammalsDF.T

aussieMammalsDF.isin({'Subclass':['marsupial'],'Origin':['native']})#OR
aussieMammalsDF.isin({'Subclass':['marsupial'],'Origin':['native']}).any(TRUE)
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? you can press TAB to get suggestion after typing aussieMammalsDF. in Jupyter Notebook. It may be different in other IDEs.

Comment: Use Shift + Tab to view the Docstring of an object

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`australianMammals?` or `?australianMammals` or `help(australianMammals)`

Plus, knowledge of selecting the right methods and attributes will come through practice. Refer to Pandas official docs for beautiful examples. Start with [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/

"Shift + Tab will show you the Docstring (documentation) for the the object you have just typed in a code cell - you can keep pressing this short cut to cycle through a few modes of documentation"